# Input fields are not showing when copy a table row using javascript

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I am working with table where copy a table row using javascript issue is that when i click on add more button then copy a table row but input fields are not showing here is my code of table

```
<table class="striped display" cellspacing="0" width="100%" id="myTable">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
       <td class="input-field col s2">
       <label>Module</label>
          <select  data-rel="chosen" name="moduleid[]" class="form-control">
              <?php 
                $RowRes=mysqli_query($con,"Select id, name from tbl_module where status=1 order by id asc");
                while($URow=mysqli_fetch_array($RowRes)){
                echo "<option value=".$URow[0].">".$URow[1]."</option>";}?>
          </select>                 
        </td>
        <td class="input-field col s2">
           <label>Week Days</label>
             <select id="week_days" data-rel="chosen" name="week_days[]" class="form-control" multiple="multiple">
              <option value="1">Monday</option>
              <option value="2">Tuesday</option>
              <option value="3">Wednesday</option>
              <option value="4">Thursday</option>
              <option value="5">Friday</option>
             </select>
          </td>
      <td><button type="button" name="add" id="more_btn" class="btn right">Add More</button></td>
     </tr>
</tbody>
```

and here is the javascript code where append a table row on button click

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
var i=1;
$('#more_btn').click(function() {
    i++;
   $('#myTable tbody').append('<tr id="row'+i+'"><td class="input-field col s2"><label>Module</label><select data-rel="chosen" name="moduleid[]" class="form-control"><?php$RowRes=mysqli_query($con,"Select id, name from tbl_module where status=1 order by id asc");while($URow=mysqli_fetch_array($RowRes)){echo "<option value=".$URow[0].">".$URow[1]."</option>";}?></select></td><td class="input-field col s2"><label>Week Days</label><select  data-rel="chosen" name="week_days[]" class="form-control" multiple="multiple"><option value="1">Monday</option><option value="2">Tuesday</option><option value="3">Wednesday</option><option value="4">Thursday</option><option value="5">Friday</option></select></td><td><button type="button" name="remove" id="'+i+'" class="btn btn-danger btn_remove">X</button></td></tr>');

   $('.btn_remove').click(function(){ 
       var button_id = $(this).attr("id");   
       $('#row'+button_id+'').remove();  
  });
});
```

});

Here is the image of issue [image]

see that first row of table input fields are working perfectly but second row of table that copy when click on **Add More** button input fields are not working

Comment: What part doesn't work? Have you tried paring down what you're inserting and adding back contents piece by piece? example: (1) `<tr></tr>`, (2) `<tr id="row'+i+'"></tr>`, ...

Comment: read my question carefully then you know it what part does not work

Comment: It's a debugging tip, really. When my code doesn't work, I strip away changes and build it back again until I see where I introduced the error.

Comment: why vote me in minus??

Comment: As others have said, you're trying to execute PHP code in your javascript code to add a new row. The php code gets rendered once, server side, it won't run again every time you use that javascript function as the output will have already been rendered. If the php only needs to be rendered once, my guess is you have a javascript error due to opening/closing quotation marks. Does your console show any javascript errors?

Comment: @TommyBs you said that without php code then its copy a table row using javascript?

Comment: Yes, you can, I've noticed you're using jquery so have a look at the clone method. https://api.jquery.com/clone/#clone-withDataAndEvents You can then update the IDs etc. in your cloned copy to your increment value as needed

Comment: I second @TommyBs, if there is a single `'` somewhere in one of the option values to your select field, then this will disturb your quotation mark balance in the JavaScript string value and will break your code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just use JQuery to achieve what you want with the clone method and remove the embeded PHP code.

A simple fiddle can be found here https://jsfiddle.net/xpvt214o/809590/ that merely updates the id of the main `<tr>` itself. But the code looks as follows:

```
       $(document).ready(function() {
var i=1;
$('#more_btn').click(function() {
    i++;
    $clone = $('#first').clone(true);
    $clone.attr('id', "row" + i);

    $clone.find('.btn_remove').attr('data-remove-id', 'row'+i);
   $('#myTable tbody').append($clone);


});

$('#myTable').on('click','.btn_remove',function(){ 
       var button_id = $(this).data("remove-id");  
       $('#'+button_id+'').remove();  
  });

});
```

The only `id` i'm manipulating here is the id of the table row itself. But using jQuery selectors you can change the ids etc. of any of the cloned elements.

I do have a sneaky suspicion your current code won't work as expected, as even in your example all the form inputs have the same names (you only seem to be updating the id of the table row). You may want to make the form names themselves more dynamic by appending the `i` elsewhere. But that is obviously a different question.

You might also want to consider just having one "Add more" button at the bottom of all the forms, rather than duplicating that as they all have the same `id` as well. And you don't want to end up with any unintended consequences bearing in mind the click handler is associated with that element.

Comment: Thank u its working perfectly but little bit issue is that where I am adding remove button when click on it then table row is removed

Comment: I've edited the code a bit to show how this should work. But any further info should either be a new question. But I would recommend spending some time attempting/understanding it first in order to try and progress your own and cement your knowledge

Comment: Thank you so much.. I am confused about remove button I was missed it in my question. Please help me on this

Comment: The code and the fiddle now show the remove button. But please don't just copy and paste blindly. Spend some time to learn what it is doing and try to understand it. And if this post solved your issue please click the tick to accept it.

Answer (score 1):

In your select the php code will not execute:

```
<select data-rel="chosen" name="moduleid[]" class="form-control"><?php$RowRes=mysqli_query($con,"Select id, name from tbl_module where status=1 order by id asc");while($URow=mysqli_fetch_array($RowRes)){echo "<option value=".$URow[0].">".$URow[1]."</option>";}?></select>
```

you need to make an api and get data from server.

On first load it works php executed on server and html response generated and that sent to browser. but by adding elements with javascript will not be able to execute php code.

Comment: Thanks for supporting.. you are think that by adding elements with javascript will not be able to execute php code. My code without php is also not working. See agian my question is updated

Comment: I am not voted in minus. Also I can't.
Atlease 125 reputation required to vote in minus.

Comment: Thanks for supporting.. your code is correct but is not working on my side

Comment: @Arslan see Mr. TommyBs added a answer that will help. I think :)